# Why is this for-loop (on an object) messing up?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I have a *for-loop* here that is confusing me greatly because it's throwing a **cannot read property of null**, even though it's coming straight from the loop...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventManager' of null
HTMLDocument.eventManager
src/jsgame/game.js:30
  27 | 
  28 | eventManager(event) {
  29 |   for (let key in this) {
> 30 |     if (typeof this[key].eventManager === 'function') {
  31 | ^       this[key].eventManager(event);
  32 |     }
  33 |   }
```

If you understand what I am trying to do, do you have suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: first thing might be add a line before that `console.log("key", key)` - that will tell you the object it's looking for and cannot find. Maybe you're loading this file out of sequence

Comment: Add where do you call `eventManager` and how. Also add the whole example that you are using.

Comment: @Kinglish ahh, so I am calling it in the addEventListener, and its definitely not looking in the right object? How can I fix this?

Comment: @Ayzrian I am referencing it in the document.addEventListener.

Comment: Please add the minimal reproducable example, e.g. the class that contains `eventManager` function and the code that uses it.

Comment: @Ayzrian I found the solution. Problematic: `document.addEventListener('keydown', game.eventManager)`. Solution: `document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => game.eventManager(event))`. Thanks for your interest and help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I was referencing it like this ...
`document.addEventListener('keydown', game.eventManager)`.

Solution:
`document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => game.eventManager(event))`

Comment: Can someone explain this one to me? My understanding of JavaScript says there's no real difference between these statements - the only difference is the second statement (the solution) defines a new function inline, where the first is passing one..why would this line cause this issue?

Comment: Nevermind found the issue - `this` won't be defined unless you `eventManager = eventManager.bind(game)` or define the function in a class to hide the bind call away from your code. Then again, not enough code was shown to know that for sure.

Comment: @RichardBarker Yes I believe you are correct; `this.eventManager = this.eventManager.bind(this)` in the Game Class constructor would have also worked.

Comment: Assuming you have `class Game ... ` that defines eventManager (in constructor or as function) then it should have been good there too - the engine should have bound the function or field automatically. there's something else going on that's hard to see without the code. But you got it working so I guess that's good.